# I can't find where to specify new credentials for my neo4j connection in the desktop browser

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I've successfully changed my username and password for my neo4j database and I can successfully connect from my app.  However now I cannot log in from the desktop browser.

Every attempt to run :server connect returns the same message, indicating that I'm still attempting to connect as user "neo4j", that the database access requires an authenticated connection, and that connection credentials are stored in my web browser.

I've checked everywhere I can think of for where these credentials are stored so I can change the user I am attempting to authenticate with.

Where is this information stored and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your issue. In the neo4j Desktop window:

1. Select your `Project` in the left pane.
2. Click the `Manage` button of the appropriate `Graph` in the right pane.
3. Click the `Administration` tab.
4. Set your new password.

Comment: This just throws an error: "Set password failed: Error: Could not change password" but I don't need to change the database password, I need to change the credentials that it's trying to access the database with.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  I had to use :server disconnect and then :server connect, which allowed me to re-enter new credentials.

Comment: I am getting ` Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.` similar to [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/password-for-neo4j-browser/7228)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your neo4j desktop installed, follow this to reset the password of a database

[image]